# How to create an msi out of my compiled debug win32 build of python 2.7.11?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, compilation, windows-installer

Thanks in advance for your help,

I have downloaded the source code of python 2.7.11 and built Debug win32 on Windows 7 using vs2015 &vs2008 as directed on this page https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows
and the {src}\pcbuild\readme.txt file.

Now that I got all the pdbs, *_d.exe and source how can I package this new compiled version in an msi?

From an admin cmd at src folder I have tried

```
.\tools\buildbot\buildmsi.bat 

Error: project file '.\PCbuild\pcbuild.sln' was not found or not a valid project file.
```

The sln exists and I can open it in my VS2008.

Comment: So then, why not open the solution in VS2008 and build it?

Comment: the solution doesn't have a project to build msi. It only has the projects for building python. 
I found that buildmsi.bat file in tools folder and no readme documentation for that tool.